# Location permission dialog not shown in android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, location, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I'm trying to apply a tutorial about request permission when the app start, but when I tested on my real device android 12, it's not show the permission dialog it show a snack bar that request from user to go to setting and grant it manually

Manifiest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--    TODO: Step 1 add in permissions for fine location and background-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".HuntMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hunt"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".GeofenceBroadcastReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this my code

```
class HuntMainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHuntMainBinding
    private lateinit var geofencingClient: GeofencingClient
    private lateinit var viewModel: GeofenceViewModel

    private val runningQOrLater = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
            android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

    // A PendingIntent for the Broadcast Receiver that handles geofence transitions.
    // TODO: Step 8 add in a pending intent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_hunt_main)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, SavedStateViewModelFactory(this.application,
            this)).get(GeofenceViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewmodel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        // TODO: Step 9 instantiate the geofencing client

        // Create channel for notifications
        createChannel(this )
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        checkPermissionsAndStartGeofencing()
    }

    /*
 *  When we get the result from asking the user to turn on device location, we call
 *  checkDeviceLocationSettingsAndStartGeofence again to make sure it's actually on, but
 *  we don't resolve the check to keep the user from seeing an endless loop.
 */
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        // TODO: Step 7 add code to check that the user turned on their device location and ask
        //  again if they did not
    }

    /*
     *  When the user clicks on the notification, this method will be called, letting us know that
     *  the geofence has been triggered, and it's time to move to the next one in the treasure
     *  hunt.
     */
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        val extras = intent?.extras
        if(extras != null){
            if(extras.containsKey(GeofencingConstants.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_INDEX)){
                viewModel.updateHint(extras.getInt(GeofencingConstants.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_INDEX))
                checkPermissionsAndStartGeofencing()
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * In all cases, we need to have the location permission.  On Android 10+ (Q) we need to have
     * the background permission as well.
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult")

        if (
            grantResults.isEmpty() ||
            grantResults[LOCATION_PERMISSION_INDEX] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
            (requestCode == REQUEST_FOREGROUND_AND_BACKGROUND_PERMISSION_RESULT_CODE &&
                    grantResults[BACKGROUND_LOCATION_PERMISSION_INDEX] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED))
        {
            Snackbar.make(
                binding.activityMapsMain,
                R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
            )
                .setAction(R.string.settings) {
                    startActivity(Intent().apply {
                        action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                        data = Uri.fromParts("package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null)
                        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    })
                }.show()
        } else {
            checkDeviceLocationSettingsAndStartGeofence()
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will also destroy any saved state in the associated ViewModel, so we remove the
     * geofences here.
     */
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        removeGeofences()
    }

    /**
     * Starts the permission check and Geofence process only if the Geofence associated with the
     * current hint isn't yet active.
     */
    private fun checkPermissionsAndStartGeofencing() {
        if (viewModel.geofenceIsActive()) return
        if (foregroundAndBackgroundLocationPermissionApproved()) {
            checkDeviceLocationSettingsAndStartGeofence()
        } else {
            requestForegroundAndBackgroundLocationPermissions()
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Uses the Location Client to check the current state of location settings, and gives the user
     *  the opportunity to turn on location services within our app.
     */
    private fun checkDeviceLocationSettingsAndStartGeofence(resolve:Boolean = true) {
        val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER
        }
        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
        val settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
        val locationSettingsResponseTask =
            settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            if (exception is ResolvableApiException && resolve){
                try {
                    exception.startResolutionForResult(this@HuntMainActivity,
                        REQUEST_TURN_DEVICE_LOCATION_ON)
                } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting location settings resolution: " + sendEx.message)
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(
                    binding.activityMapsMain,
                    R.string.location_required_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
                ).setAction(android.R.string.ok) {
                    checkDeviceLocationSettingsAndStartGeofence()
                }.show()
            }
        }
        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnCompleteListener {
            if ( it.isSuccessful ) {
                addGeofenceForClue()
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Determines whether the app has the appropriate permissions across Android 10+ and all other
     *  Android versions.
     */
    @TargetApi(29)
    private fun foregroundAndBackgroundLocationPermissionApproved(): Boolean {
        val foregroundLocationApproved = (
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        val backgroundPermissionApproved =
            if (runningQOrLater) {
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                        )
            } else {
                true
            }
        return foregroundLocationApproved && backgroundPermissionApproved
    }

    /*
     *  Requests ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and (on Android 10+ (Q) ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.
     */
    @TargetApi(29 )
    private fun requestForegroundAndBackgroundLocationPermissions() {
        if (foregroundAndBackgroundLocationPermissionApproved())
            return
        var permissionsArray = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        val resultCode = when {
            runningQOrLater -> {
                permissionsArray += Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                REQUEST_FOREGROUND_AND_BACKGROUND_PERMISSION_RESULT_CODE
            }
            else -> REQUEST_FOREGROUND_ONLY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Request foreground only location permission")
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this@HuntMainActivity,
            permissionsArray,
            resultCode
        )
    }
    /*
     * Adds a Geofence for the current clue if needed, and removes any existing Geofence. This
     * method should be called after the user has granted the location permission.  If there are
     * no more geofences, we remove the geofence and let the viewmodel know that the ending hint
     * is now "active."
     */
    private fun addGeofenceForClue() {
        // TODO: Step 10 add in code to add the geofence
    }

    /**
     * Removes geofences. This method should be called after the user has granted the location
     * permission.
     */
    private fun removeGeofences() {
        // TODO: Step 12 add in code to remove the geofences
    }
    companion object {
        internal const val ACTION_GEOFENCE_EVENT =
            "HuntMainActivity.treasureHunt.action.ACTION_GEOFENCE_EVENT"
    }
}

private const val REQUEST_FOREGROUND_AND_BACKGROUND_PERMISSION_RESULT_CODE = 33
private const val REQUEST_FOREGROUND_ONLY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34
private const val REQUEST_TURN_DEVICE_LOCATION_ON = 29
private const val TAG = "HuntMainActivity"
private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_INDEX = 0
private const val BACKGROUND_LOCATION_PERMISSION_INDEX = 1
```

I tested it on my real device, what i excopecting is showing the permission dialog when the app starts

[image]

Comment: You need to request first only the foreground location permission